# На чем лучше написать бэкенд mdm систему?

Tags: javascript, python, django, node.js, postgresql

Стоит задача написать бэкенд для mdm системы. Проще становиться, когда уже знаешь на чем будет бд т.к. вся организация сидит на postgresql.
Я не могу сделать выбор на чем писать.
У меня есть пару вариантов:

1. Node.js + postgresql
2. Django + postgresql
   И то и другое я вообще буду трогать впервые, но немного есть знания и малый прикладной опыт по node.js,
   буду благодарен за ваши точки зрения и советы.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучше будет писать на одной кодовой базе, скорей всего фронт у вас на js + react/vue/angular, то лучше будет писать бэк на node.js

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо большое, но можете сказать по react, vue и по angular ?  На чем будет быстрее и легче написать ?

Comment: Так ты ж бекенд собрался писать, зачем тебе реакт\вуйка\ангуляр?

Comment: на React будет лучше по моему мнению